# OAuth (from “httr”) to LinkedIn on a Shiny server

Tags: r, oauth, linkedin-api, shiny-server, httr

I’m trying to connect to the LinkedIn API using OAuth from the 'httr' library on a 'Shiny' server. I have wrapped the locally working OAuth example from [GitHub/hadley/httr](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth1-linkedin.r), with a Shiny client ui and server side. I get the client ui working.

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar( 
  sidebarPanel (
  textInput("userEmail", "Your email address:", value =""),
  submitButton("Grant Permission")
  ),
  mainPanel()
))
```

But, the serve side doesn't open a browser for authentication.

```
library(shiny)
library(httr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$GrantPermission <- reactive ({

    linkedin <- oauth_endpoint("requestToken", "authorize", "accessToken", base_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/")

    myapp <- oauth_app("linkedin", key = "abc", secret = "def")

    token <- oauth1.0_token(linkedin, myapp)

    sig <- sign_oauth1.0(myapp, token$oauth_token, token$oauth_token_secret)

    save.image(paste(input$userEmail, ".RData"))
  })
})
```

session Info:
R version: 2.15.3
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Packages: httr_0.2; shiny_0.8.0.99.

Any clue about what might be the problem?

Comment: You might try using use_oob in the dev version, but I don't think httr's OAuth support is quite ready for this use case

Comment: Thank you for proposing to try the development version solution and for all of your great contributions, Dear Hadley! I have used install_github("httr") that attached httr_0.2.99. From the httr's documentation use_oob = TRUE is only available in OAuth 2.0. However, I was not able to use OAuth 2.0 successfully with LinkedIn.

Comment: We are progressing and moving forward! Using the use_oob = TRUE argument in oauth2.0_token provided a URL and prompted for entering authorization code. However, when I had tried to open the url in Firefox v25, I received a Content Encoding Error. 
Please point your browser to the following url: 

  https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth//authorize?client_id=123&scope=&redirect_uri=urn%3Aa%3Ab%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code
  
Enter authorization code:

Content Encoding Error 
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Answer (score 4):

I think I had a similar problem with oAuth and twitteR. It turned out to be an SSL issue and was solved by adding the following:

```
require(RCurl) 
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, Troy! Although the code is working correctly locally without a certificate, I tried your solution on a Shiny server, and I made some progress by running it from the RStudio console. It did open a browser window for authentication—thank you, again! But, after granting the permission, it tried to return on the server to http://localhost:8787/custom/OAuth/cred?oauth_token=abc&oauth_verifier=def. Any idea?

Comment: I would vote your answer up, but it requires 15 points reputation—I only have 1.